# Validando request no Spring Boot com Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

Estou criando uma API que chama um serviço WSDL que precisa ser autenticado com certificados, rodando local na IDE ele funciona normalmente mas quando compilo Dockerfile para ter a imagem e criar um container apartir dele ficando dando erro de autenticação, sabem dizer se precisa de algulma configuração especifica para usar ele ?

Comando de compilação

```
docker build -t projeto-api:1.0.0 .
```

Erro

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "message": "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target",
    "timeStamp": 1695741797549
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17
WORKDIR /app

# COPY Certs
COPY ["certs/*.cer", "$JAVA_HOME/lib/security"]
COPY ["certs/*.crt", "$JAVA_HOME/lib/security"]
COPY ["certs/*.pfx", "./certs/"]
COPY ["certs/*.trustStore", "./certs/"]
COPY ["certs/*.jks", "./certs/"]
RUN chmod -R 755 ./certs/

COPY startup.sh /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/startup.sh

# Copy java
COPY target/*.jar /app/batch.jar
EXPOSE 8080

#CMD ["java", "-jar", "batch.jar"]
CMD ["/bin/bash","-c","./startup.sh"]
```

startup.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

keytool -import -trustcacerts -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias certificado_01 -file $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/certificado_01.cer

keytool -import -trustcacerts -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias certificado_02 -file $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/certificado_02.cer

keytool -import -trustcacerts -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias certificado_03 -file $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/certificado_03.cer

keytool -import -trustcacerts -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias certificado_04 -file $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/certificado_04.cer

keytool -import -trustcacerts -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias certificado_05 -file $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/certificado_05.crt

java -jar /app/batch.jar
```

Observações:

O serviço roda na AWS, ja subi uma versão de homologação e acontece o mesmo erro equanto local funciona.

Comment: você diz que local funciona, fica a dúvida se local você está executando a aplicação via o container docker, ou se está utilizando a "build" gerada pela IDE.

Comment: Utilizando container docker da o erro se eu usar o build da IDE funciona

Comment: pois é, minha sugestão é debugar no container docker para encontrar a causa raiz do problema, mas pela mensagem de erro, parece ser um erro [deste tipo](https://betterjavacode.com/programming/how-to-resolve-pkix-path-building-failed-in-docker-container), talvez esta seja uma solução. Mas apenas com essas informações fornecidas não dá sugerir nenhuma correção.